# Code Skipping Over Recordset Input, ADODB Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado

Today has been a YouTube and Internet scouring day, and I haven't quite figured out how to get this code to work. It opens and closes the connection without trouble but when I try to write to a recordset it completely skips over everything and closes the connection without inputting any Data.

```
Const AccessConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Vision\Database\BVAS.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Private Sub BtnSave_Click()

    Dim DbConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Inventory As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim r As Range

    Set DbConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Inventory = New ADODB.Recordset

    DbConn.ConnectionString = AccessConnStr
    DbConn.Open
       On Error GoTo CloseConnection
        With Inventory
            .ActiveConnection = DbConn
            .Source = "T3Scaffold_Inventory"
            .LockType = adLockOptimistic
            .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
            .Open
            On Error GoTo CloseRecordset
        End With
            CountSheet.Activate
                'WTF, why does it skip this ? Research if and IF or Do WHILE statement will work here for so that only the Items with quantity >0 are sent to ACCESS
                    For Each r In .Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

                            With Inventory
                                .AddNew
                                .Fields("ScaffoldID") = Range("ScaffoldID")
                                .Fields("ItemNumber") = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
                                .Fields("Quantity") = Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
                                .Fields("WorktypeID") = Range("WorktypeID")
                                .Fields("RentStartDate") = Range("Date")
                                .Fields("OnRent?") = "Yes"
                                .Update
                            End With

                    Next r


CloseRecordset:
    Inventory.CancelUpdate
    Inventory.Close

CloseConnection:
    DbConn.Close

Set Inventory = Nothing
Set DbConn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thanks Everyone. I hope that this is a super complicated solution lol.
-MC

Comment: So it gets to the line starting "For Each r in .range" and then skips straight to "CloseRecordset:" ?

Comment: I put a Break point it at the for each statement and it skips right over it. It goes from 'End With' to 'CloseRecordset:' Without iterating through the loop.

Comment: The fact that it's skipping straight to the `CloseRecordset` label suggests that `CountSheet.Activate` is generating an error condition. Just before the `End With` you have `On Error GoTo CloseRecordset`. Try adding a line just after the `CloseRecordset` label to see what the error is: `MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description`

Comment: I'll Try that but wouldn't that generate a run-time error or something when it's stepping through the code? I will Edit if that is successful.

Comment: Also consider moving the On Error lines to a place before you start using the objects: move `On Error GoTo CloseConnection` before `DbConn.Open` (or even 1 line before that); move `On Error GoTo CloseRecordset` before `With Inventory`, so they catch errors while using them.

Comment: I did modify the code to include the msgbox and that has been helping @skippy, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error because of

```
For Each r In .Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

on error ,  On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

the code to be changed like this

```
For Each r In Activesheet.Range("A2", Activesheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

or

```
For Each r In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: The only thing I also had to modify `CountSheet.activate` to `Worksheets("CountSheet").Activate` .